# Jooq dsl one to many relations

Tags: java, jooq

I'm using Spring Data + Jooq DSL. As result entity I'm using not jooq generated entity, but simple one, without any annotations and for relations One To Many getting result:

```
[{
   "id":2,
   "name":"James",
   "addresses":[
      {
         "id":null,
         "country":null,
         "street":null
      }
   ]
}]
```

Is any way to return an empty array for addresses?

My code to perform a request:

```
    public Set<User> getUserById(Set<Long> id) {
        Set<User> result = new HashSet<>();
        ResultQuery users = dsl.select(
                field("u.id", Long.class).as("id"),
                field("u.name", String.class).as("name"),
                field("a.id", Long.class).as("addresses_id"),
                field("a.country", String.class).as("addresses_country"),
                field("a.street", String.class).as("addresses_street")
        ).from("schema.user_table u")
                .leftJoin("schema.address_table a")
                .on("u.id = a.user_id")
                .where(field("u.id").in(id));
        try(ResultSet rs = users.fetchResultSet()) {
            JdbcMapper<User> mapper = JdbcMapperFactory
                    .newInstance()
                    .addKeys("id")
                    .newMapper(User.class);
            result = mapper.stream(rs).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Check this out https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I think it's too complicated, because the current spring-boot release provides jooq 3.14.13, and multiset is a new feature of 3.15. I have added my fix as an answer.

Comment: You can always use the newest version of JOOQ with Spring Boot. Simply set jooq.version in the properties. Why do you don't use the jOOQ generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just [use SQL/JSON to produce JSON documents directly from within your database](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/11/13/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/)?

```java
public String getUserById(Set<Long> id) {
    return dsl.select(coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(
        jsonObject(
            key("id").value(field("u.id", Long.class)),
            key("name").value(field("u.name", String.class)),
            key("addresses").value(coalesce(
                jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
                    key("id").value(field("a.id", Long.class)),
                    key("country").value(field("a.country", String.class)),
                    key("street").value(field("a.street", String.class))
                )),
                jsonArray()
            ))
        ),
        jsonArray()
    )))
    .from("schema.user_table u")
    .leftJoin("schema.address_table a")
    .on("u.id = a.user_id")
    .where(field("u.id").in(id))
    .fetchSingle().value1().data();
}
```

If you really need the intermediate `User` representation, then you can either:

- [Use Jackson or Gson to map the JSON document to the nested `User` DTO structure using reflection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/) (works with jOOQ 3.14)
- Use jOOQ 3.15's new [`MULTISET` value constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) operator or [`MULTISET_AGG` aggregate function](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) along with [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), see below:

```java
public Set<User> getUserById(Set<Long> id) {
    return dsl.select(
        field("u.id", Long.class),
        field("u.name", String.class),
        multisetAgg(
            field("a.id", Long.class),
            field("a.country", String.class),
            field("a.street", String.class)
        ).convertFrom(r -> r == null 
            ? Collections.<Address>emptyList() 
            : r.map(Records.mapping(Address::new)))
    )
    .from("schema.user_table u")
    .leftJoin("schema.address_table a")
    .on("u.id = a.user_id")
    .where(field("u.id").in(id))
    .fetchSet(Records.mapping(User::new));
}
```

#### Side note on code generation and execution

While not strictly relevant to this question, unless your schema is dynamic (not known at compile time), I really urge you to reconsider using [source code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/). If you're not using it, you're missing out on *a lot* of jOOQ API advantages, just like when you're executing a jOOQ query with something other than jOOQ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice, I have started to work with generated entities.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked specify as a key addressId:

```
.addKeys("id", "addresses_id")
```